# RAID1 restoring and upgrading

Tags: raid-1, centos-5

I have a server running CentOS 5 in a software Raid 1 (2 Drives)

One of the drives has degraded and these drives are SATA 250GB @ 3Gbps not 6Gbps, I was wondering what If I slapped in a 500GB @ 6Gbps HDD would Linux automatically rebuild on the new drive without an issue?

I asked this because I want to migrate the drive to a newer hdd without having to reinstall everything. Or is my only option going to be to migrate with some other process like clonezilla (except i've read that clonevilla will not clone software/fake raid)

Comment: If your software raid is mdadm then you should be able to create a partition on your new drive that matches the partition on the other, and load that into the raid. It will rebuild it gradually and you can check the progress in /proc/mdstat. This explains it: https://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array

Comment: _Wahyit Cheung_, what's the motherboard make and model, the drive make and model,, and how did you generate the Software RAID array? Please click [edit] and update your question with this useful information.

Comment: Ill try and find that information, but the raid was configured with CentOS software raid during the installation process, its not like Intel raid I assume its more like windows raid.